# I know how to code/config SF, but I don't know how to use it

Tags: discussion

I've been coding and configuring Salesforce for about 2 years. Most of that two years has involved custom objects and making custom apps and user interfaces.

I've realized that I don't actually know how to use Salesforce, in its pure vanilla form.

Let me use this analogy to help me explain my situation:

Many of us know how to drive a car, be a driver, but few us can actually customize our vehicle, mechanic: go under the hood to fix/upgrade something, body work, new paint job, change breaks, etc.

Basically, I'm a mechanic of Salesforce, but I'm not a good driver of Salesforce.

How to do I become a better driver? What resource is there that explains how to "drive" Salesforce?

Comment: This question isn't really about the Stack Exchange. I don't know that it's appropriate to post here on Meta.

Comment: @AdrianLarson this is Salesforce Meta, why not?

Comment: Meta is meant primarily for questions about the exchange itself. Take a look at [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta): *Please...avoid asking questions that have nothing to do with Salesforce Stack Exchange or the Stack Exchange network. This is not a random discussion area; rather, it's a place for improving our community and website, together.*